# Can Indian travel to US with passport expiring in 5 months

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, passport-renewals

My mom lives in India (she is an Indian citizen). Her passport expires in September 2021. Her visa is valid until the end of 2022.

Can she travel to US around July and be back in India before her passport expires? I think there was some 6 month rule, but then I read an article that said that it doesn't apply to Indians. So I'm not sure.

They plan to take Qatar airlines, with a stop-over at Doha. Are there any similar issues I should be concerned about at Doha?

Comment: Please see [SIX-MONTH CLUB UPDATE](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2017-Dec/Six-Month%20Club%20Update122017.pdf). *Visitors traveling to the United States are required to be in possession of passports that are valid for six months beyond the period of their intended stay in the United States.  Citizens of the countries listed below are exempt the six-month rule and need only have a passport valid for their intended period of stay.*

Comment: _"Effective May 4, the entry into the United States of certain nonimmigrant travelers who have been physically present in India is suspended"_  - https://in.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/

Comment: @WeatherVane that's an answer